# Why does this Google API call need authorization?

Tags: oauth, authorization, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm writing an iOS application that pulls events from public Google Calendars. **The app will only ever deal with public calendars** that can be accessed by everyone regardless of whether or not the user has a Google account. Consequently, I thought I could disregard authorization completely.

Apparently I'm wrong, though, because I've run into a strange problem...

When I make an [`Events: list`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) call on my public test calendar, everything works perfectly. I get a list of all the events for the given public calendar, and I even get some metadata for the calendar itself.

When I make a [`Calendars: get`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/get) call, however, I get a "401 Unauthorized" response. The perplexing part is that I actually get more information about the calendar using `Events: list` than if I use `Calendars: get`, and yet the former doesn't require any authorization!

Can someone explain what's going on here? Why can I make an `Events: list` call without authorization but not a `Calendars: get` one?